# $\operatorname{Ann}(W)$ is naturally isomorphic to $(V /W)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $W$ is a subspace of $V$, show that $\operatorname{Ann}(W)$ is naturally isomorphic to $(V /W)^*$.

Derive that $\operatorname{Ann}(\operatorname{Ann}(W)) = W$.

Here Ann represents the annihilator.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi \in \operatorname{Ann}(W)$, then it is a form on $V$ (i.e. $\phi \in V^\ast$) such that $W$ is in its kernel. So it induces a map $V/W \to k$, i.e. an element of $(V/W)^*$.

I let you show it is an isomorphism.